# To exit out of the code if expect condition not met RHEL

Tags: bash, shell, expect, rhel

I have written a small code using `expect` in Red Hat Linux 8 to check if a host is reachable using ICMP Ping. My intention is if the destination is not reachable , then the execution should break.Please find below the code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
lassign $argv 1 2
spawn ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 $1
 expect  {
    " 0%" {puts "Source is reachable!"}
    " 100%" {puts "Source is not rechable. Please restart IPSEC and check!"}
     eof {break\r }
    }
```

However with the above break statement, the execution is getting continued to next line. I am new to `expect` in bash scripting.Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464272/expect-how-to-exit-with-status-code-1-if-a-command-fails

Comment: use "exit" statement

Comment: Hi , but "exit" is not working in this case with "expect"

Comment: Be careful the pattern might have to be `" 100.0%"`

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you don't need expect for this: there's nothing that needs interaction. In plain bash

```sh
result=$( ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 "$1 )
if [[ $result == *"100.0% packet loss"* ]]; then
    echo "not reachable"
fi
```

---

Since you're already in expect, you can use [any Tcl command](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm):

```
set result [exec ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 $1]
if {[string first { 100.0%} $result] != -1} {
    puts "Source not reachable"
}
```

I'm a huge fan of expect, but if a process doesn't need interaction, there are simpler approaches.

---

I forgot about Tcl's error handling for `exec` commands: if the exec'ed command returns non-zero, or if it emits any output to stderr, exec will throw an error. The way to exec ping is:

```
if {[catch {exec ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 $1} result] != 0} {
    puts "ping returned non-zero: $result"
    if {[string first { 100.0%} $result] != -1} {
        puts "Source not reachable"
    }
}
```

[Exhaustively documented on the Tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/exec#1a39e854c66866d4b4567dcb8126b8f0914bdab191eea3a4812f3ca8d9d2bff3)

Comment: Thank you but in later part of my code i am using ssh to connect to this remote server so expect is used. Thats why i need a break statement which can be used here with expect

Comment: First, `break\r` is not an expect command. Second, `break` is only allowed within a loop: where's the loop?

Comment: Hi Glenn, with the above  TCL command i am getting the following error:                             `2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms
pipe 2
child process exited abnormally
    while executing
"exec ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 $1"
    invoked from within
"set result [exec ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 $1]"
    (file "./rtest.exp" line 5)`

Answer (score 0):

I have added like below the code is working fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
lassign $argv 1 2
spawn ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 $1
expect  {
   " 0%" {puts "Source is rechable!"}
   " 100.0%" {puts "Source is not rechable.Please restart IPSEC and check!";exit 1}
        }
```